# Query parquet file by specific key in nested column map with Apache Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, parquet

Here is the parquet file schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- samples: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- some_other_value: string (nullable = false)
```

I'd like to fetch all ids and matched samples where sample's key equals to some value. For example:

```
select id, samples where key(samples) in ("abc") // Note: pseudo SQL
```

How to write query like this for Apache Spark?